# browsing an application's default page redirects to localhost/default.aspx and gives 404 error

Tags: iis-7, default

There is a login page on my app, once I login, it should redirect to Default.aspx:
On VS local setup, the URL for redirect is like this-
    "http://mydomain.com/testApp/account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/Default.aspx"
which redirects to   "http://mydomain.com/testApp/Default.aspx"

Now I have published an application on IIS7, and I am able to browse it directly.

But when I login, the redirect page is always coming as :
mydomain.com/Default.aspx instead of mydomain.com/testApp/Default.aspx.

I did try setting default page as testApp/Default.aspx, but this does not help.

Do I need to change the querystring for running on IIS?

If I run the app directly and type mydomain.com/testApp/Default.aspx, it works fine.

Any pointers?

Note: Please replace mydomain.com with locahost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the issue. The relative path in Query string for redirect should have ~ to access root folder after deployment on IIS.